# confusion with do while loops and variables

Tags: java, loops, variables, do-while

I am currently in a beginner java course and we have a homework assignment where we are required to use loops. I am trying to use a do while loop and ask a user a question. If the user responds yes the loop continues and if they say no it ends. I am using BlueJ and I keep getting an error when I enter my statement for the while stating that my variable is not found. Please let me know what I am doing wrong -- Thank you all so much :)

[image]

Comment: share your code please?

Comment: Please put the code as *text* in the question rather than as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

your variable `choice` should be declared before `do {...}` block

Answer (score 1):

The choise variable is defined inside of the do scope and is therefore not available when you reach the while part.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String choise;
do
{
  choise = ...
} while(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `choice` variable is out of scope of the while loop, hence you cannot use it in your `while` clause.

What you can do is create a boolean variable outside:

```
boolean isFinished = false;
do {
    ...
    // change isFinished to true when "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)   
    // or "y".equalsIgnoreCase(choice) :)
} while (!isFinished)
```